# Android: Reduce time spent in garabage collection

Tags: android, concurrency, garbage-collection

I am having problems with my openGL audio visualizer falling behind the music. I recently changed to a mulithreaded approach. Everything works great on Samsung S3, but on HTC Evo the audio visualizer falls behind the music.

Four threads in pipeline from audio input to visualization, AudioIn -> AudioProc -> UI -> openGL. I thought the problem may be with openGL, but I started clearing the messageque before adding a new msg to the requestRender() method. didn't help.

I think the problem is between AudioIn to AudioProc, that is the AudioProc is taking too long and building up que. I am continuously getting Logcats for GC_CONCURRENT ~43ms. which is about 2 or 3 frames at 60Hz. The Allocation tracker in DDMS suggests many allocations on the AudioProc thread. So I removed the allocations and replaced them with private float[] objects in my DSP class.

But then the Allocations started showing some calls to "java reflect array", and the GC_CONCURRENT calls got a little longer. I thought it might be because I declare the DSP class ref object in my UI thread, and I am using it in my AudioProc thread, so I changed my code to call the assign mDSP in my AudioProc thread, but now the logcat shows "JIT unchain all" calls to the AudioProc thread and GC_CONCURRENT times of 700+ms.

Obviously I am missing something fundamental, please speculate. I can post code.

Comment: I'm guessing "java reflect array" is `java.lang.reflect.Array`.  You should be able to tell more from the stack trace you get by clicking on entries in Allocation Tracker.  "JIT unchain all" means a thread is taking a really long time to suspend, and the VM suspects the thread might be spinning in compiled code, so it's breaking apart some of the compiled code to ensure it hits a safe-point and suspends.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The stack trace was hiding at the bottom, so your comment helps. I spent all day yesterday on this, and I will add some notes above, but the problem remains that the AudioIn thread is creating more work than the AudioProc thread can handle... Maybe the Samsung S3 just has a better processor, or the HTC isn't multithreaded so the GC_Concurrency is not happening conccurently...

Comment: The concurrent GC log looks like `GC_CONCURRENT freed 412K, 5% free 8958K/9396K, paused 4ms+1ms, total 35ms`.  The important numbers are the pause times, since those indicate times when *all* threads have been paused.  The "total" time is less important on a multi-core device because ideally it's happening concurrently.  Other GC messages (like `GC_FOR_ALLOC`, `GC_EXPLICIT`, `WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC`) are more of a problem for real-time processing.